# Remove GPS on matrice 100

Tags: dji-sdk

With my team we are programming indoor flight for the matrice 100, and we don't have the use of the GPS.
Is it possible to remove it?
And sometimes at the floor level we have electromagnetic problems, and the drone refuses to turn on the rotors, are they any way to force it ?
We use guidance, and I have noticed even without GPS and with electromagnetic interference the drone is stable.

Answer (score 1):

As of Mar 2018, on ALL DJI drones you need to have at least the compass connected in order to start flight.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just remove the GPS module from the M100? The module rises above the rest of the craft; it's that little white puck with "DJI" written on it in red.

Alternatively, I've heard of people covering it with tin foil to prevent the GPS signal from coming through.

Comment: The drone won't start to fly if the GPS is not connected. I tried with aluminium, it works but i would like to retire completely the module from the drone.

Comment: @PedroSucre even if the remote controller is in "A" mode?

Comment: In A mod it will not use the GPS, but I think it use the compass, which is in the same module (the white module above the drone), I successfully desactivate the GPS (With assistant 2 in the debug mod) but I can't find how to desactivate the compass, which is causing the warning with the electromagnetic noise.