# dji matrice 100 usage with GPS plugged out

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I am using DJI Matrice 100 for indoor usage. I intend to use dji_sdk ROS library (http://wiki.ros.org/dji_sdk) to control the drone. The idea is to do path tracking. However, I do not want to use the GPS at all. General question: How do I get this done?

Specific questions:

- How can I get the system to start with the GPS turned-off/unplugged? Someone here ([Remove GPS on matrice 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432305/remove-gps-on-matrice-100)) suggested that the latest update allows the system to take-off if the magnetometer is there but I do not find this to be the case.
- I have a few options of controlling the drone by publishing on specific rostopics listed on the dji_sdk ROS page above. While I have successfully simulated this in the dji simulation environment, doing this in reality requires the direction of motion in the ENU direction to be known. Thus it requires the GPS to be ever-present. I do not know if there is a way to provide these commands in the the body-frame of the drone.

Please feel free to ask for any details you need!

Edit: For the 2nd part of the question, I was hoping someone would refer to dji_sdk ROS library (http://wiki.ros.org/dji_sdk) and tell me that I can use the rostopic **/dji_sdk/flight_control_setpoint_generic** to control the drone in the body-frame of the drone (as somehow referred to at the end of the page). If this is indeed true and using the flag you can achieve this, does someone know what should the value be for doing position control/velocity control in the body-fixed frame?

Comment: I think this is a firmware issue. Also, I have never this drone taking off w/o GNNS even indoors. So what is the deal behind removing GNSS? Weight issues?

Comment: @Tik0 thanks for the comment. The idea is to have my own positioning system take care of this.